# How to call scrapy spider inside django view using spider.CrawlerRunner() or CrawlerProcess()

Tags: python, django, python-3.x, scrapy, django-2.0

After going to all the links in Stack Overflow as well as other git etc. too, I am unable to solve my error. Basically, I want to **scrap instagram** by giving specific hashtag i.e. User will give a hashtag from Django UI and Django function will send that hashtag to scrapy spider for crawling using

> scrapy.spider.spider.CrawlProcess()

**Hope for the help !**

Following is my code:

**django/models.py**

```
from django.db import models

class InstaAccountDetails(models.Model):
    website = models.URLField()
    post_id = models.PositiveIntegerField() 
    shortcode = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    caption = models.CharField(max_length=500)
    display_url = models.ImageField()
    loc_id = models.PositiveIntegerField()
    loc_name = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    loc_lat = models.IntegerField()
    loc_lon = models.IntegerField()
    owner_id = models.PositiveIntegerField()
    owner_name = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    taken_at_timestamp = models.DateField()

    def __str__(self):
        return self.owner_name
```

**django/views.py**

```
from django.shortcuts import render, redirect
from django.http import JsonResponse
from scrapy.crawler import CrawlerProcess, CrawlerRunner
from scrapy.utils.project import get_project_settings
from instagram_scrapy.instagram_scrapy.spiders.instaCrawler import InstagramSpider

def home(request):
    return render(request, 'instagram_link_app/homePage.html')

def get_insta_details(request):
    field_value = request.GET.get('value_holder')
    print("request value ::::::::::::::: ",field_value)
    try:
        if field_value:
            return JsonResponse({"msg:" "Hii"})
            process = CrawlerProcess(get_project_settings())

            process.crawl(InstagramSpider(hashtag=field_value))
            process.start()  #the script will block here until the crawling is finished
            print(process)
            data['process'] = process
            return JsonResponse(data)
        else:
            return JsonResponse({'message': 'None'})
    except Exception as e:
        return JsonResponse({'message': str(e)})
```

**scrapy/settings.py**

```
import os
import sys
import django
BOT_NAME = 'instagram_scrapy'
SPIDER_MODULES = ['instagram_scrapy.spiders']
NEWSPIDER_MODULE = 'instagram_scrapy.spiders'
ITEM_PIPELINES = {
   'instagram_scrapy.pipelines.InstagramScrapyPipeline': 800,
}
sys.path.append(os.path.join(os.path.dirname("..")))
os.environ['DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE'] = 'instagram_link.settings'
django.setup()
```

**scrapy/myspiders.py**

```
import scrapy
import json
import time
import os.path
from instagram_scrapy.instagram_scrapy.items import InstaAccountItem
class InstagramSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = "instaCrawler"  # Name of the Spider, required value

    def init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        try:
            print("kwargs:::::::::", kwargs)
            self.hashtag = kwargs.get('hashtag','myinterior')
            print(":::::::", self.hashtag)
            self.start_urls = ["https://www.instagram.com/explore/tags/" + self.hashtag + "/?__a=1"]
            print("start_urls:::::::", self.start_urls)
            self.date = time.strftime("%d-%m-%Y_%H")
            self.checkpoint_path = './scraped/%s/%s/.checkpoint' % (self.name, self.hashtag)
            print("checkpoint_path:::::::", self.checkpoint_path)
            self.custom_settings = {
                'FEED_URI': './scraped/%s/%s/%s' % (self.name, self.hashtag, self.date),
            }
            print("self.custom_settings:::::::::::::::::::::: ",self.custom_settings)
            # super(InstagramSpider, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        except Exception as e:
            print("Error:::::::",str(e))
     def parse(self, response):
        return self.parse_htag(response)
```

**scrapy/piplines.py**

```
from scrapy.utils.serialize import ScrapyJSONEncoder

_encoder = ScrapyJSONEncoder()


class InstagramScrapyPipeline(object):
    def process_item(self, item, spider):
        item.save()
        return item
```

**scrapy/items.py**

```
import scrapy
from scrapy.item import Field
from scrapy_djangoitem import DjangoItem
from instagram_link_app.models import InstaAccountDetails

class InstaAccountItem(DjangoItem):
    django_model = InstaAccountDetails
```

**My Error**

In django/admin page

```
OperationalError at /admin/instagram_link_app/instaaccountdetails/

no such column: instagram_link_app_instaaccountdetails.website
```

Error after entering hashtag

```
Internal Server Error: /get_insta_details/
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/chandniabhatia/Documents/Chandni/Django/Django_Project_POCs/scraper_instagram/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/handlers/exception.py", line 35, in inner
    response = get_response(request)
  File "/home/chandniabhatia/Documents/Chandni/Django/Django_Project_POCs/scraper_instagram/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 128, in _get_response
    response = self.process_exception_by_middleware(e, request)
  File "/home/chandniabhatia/Documents/Chandni/Django/Django_Project_POCs/scraper_instagram/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 126, in _get_response
    response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
  File "/home/chandniabhatia/Documents/Chandni/Django/Django_Project_POCs/scraper_instagram/instagram_link/instagram_link_app/views.py", line 76, in get_insta_details
    return JsonResponse({"msg:" "Hii"})
  File "/home/chandniabhatia/Documents/Chandni/Django/Django_Project_POCs/scraper_instagram/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/http/response.py", line 503, in __init__
    'In order to allow non-dict objects to be serialized set the '
TypeError: In order to allow non-dict objects to be serialized set the safe parameter to False.
```